# How can I fill my wpf datagrid with my list (of t)

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have two classes named **Breed** and **PetType**, these also are my tables in my sql server database

The **Breed** class is this:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string BreedName { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public int SortOrder { get; set; }
public bool StatusId { get; set; }
public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
public string CreatedByName { get; set; }
public int PetTypeId { get; set; } //Inner or left joined from PetTypes Table(stored procedure)
public string PetTypeName { get; set; }
```

The **PetType** class is this:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string PetTypeName { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public int SortOrder { get; set; }
public bool StatusId { get; set; }
public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
public string CreatedByName { get; set; }
```

then in my DataAccessLayer project,

```
    public List<Breed> RetrieveMany(Breed parameters)
    {
        var items = new List<Breed>();
        var command = new SqlCommand {CommandText = "SP_RetrieveBreeds", CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure};

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", parameters.Id).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", parameters.BreedName).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PetTypeId", parameters.PetTypeId).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        DataTable dt = SqlHelper.GetData(command);

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            var item = new Breed();
            item.Id = Convert.ToInt32(row["Id"].ToString());
            item.PetTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(row["PetTypeId"].ToString());
            item.PetTypeName = (row["PetTypeName"]).ToString();
            item.BreedName =  row["BreedName"].ToString();
            item.Description =  row["Description"].ToString();
            item.SortOrder = Convert.ToInt32(row["SortOrder"].ToString());
            item.CreatedBy = Convert.ToInt32(row["CreatedById"].ToString());
            item.CreatedByName =  row["CreatedByName"].ToString();

            items.Add(item);
        }

        return items;
    }
```

Then i declare itemMgr as an object. put these items in a list of  object

```
BreedDataAccess itemMgr =  new BreedDataAccess();

public void LoadGridview()
    {
        Breed BreedParam = RetrieveFilter(searchCrit); //gets all filter parameters for individual searching
        //this.itemMgr.EntityList = itemMgr.RetrieveMany(itemMgr.Parameters);


        List <Breed> listOfBreeds = new List<Breed>();

        listOfBreeds = DataAcessLayer.RetrieveMany(BreedParam); 

        this.dgvBreeds.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.dgvBreeds.ItemSource = this.itemMgr.EntityList;
    }
```

This is what I tried for my mark up:

```
<Window x:Class="NeoClinic.WPFTryOut.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgvBreeds" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="319" Width="517"/>
</Grid>
```

I tried the code in windows form DataGridView and it worked just fine.
But I don't know how to do it in WPF.

Comment: can you try this.dgvBreeds.ItemSource = listOfBreeds as a first step and see if that populates the grid? And set AutoGenerateColumns to true.

Comment: why are you setting itemsource to this.itemMgr.EntityList when you are fetching data in listOfBreeds?

Comment: Also this link should help you out... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f1c61aae-0604-4486-8279-54747ed95e2d/binding-a-list-to-a-wpf-datagrid?forum=wpf

Comment: Try to set `AutoGenerateColumns = true;` (currently it is set to `false` but no column declared in XAML??!)

Comment: ow my bad, i was sleepy that time i didnt realized
it should be this.dgvBreeds.ItemSource = listOfBreeds;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're handling events, presumably in the code behind of the window / control. This creates a strong coupling between the UI elements and the logic that sits behind, which in turn makes testing a lot harder.

I would consider using the [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and doing this sort of thing in the View Model. Using this approach you can reduce the coupling between UI (View) and the logic (View Model).

I've put together a very simple application (targeting .Net 4.5) to demonstrate binding a collection to the data grid and how to delete the selected row.

Here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding People}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
            <Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}">Delete Selected Row</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }
    }
```

Person.cs

```
using System;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Forename { get; set; }

        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DelegateCommand.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute,
                       Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (_canExecute == null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
            {
                CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    internal class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
            DeleteCommand = new DelegateCommand(x => DeleteSelectedItem(null));

            People.Add(new Person { Forename = "Bob", Surname = "Smith" });
            People.Add(new Person { Forename = "Alice", Surname = "Jones" });
        }

        private void DeleteSelectedItem(object obj)
        {
            People.Remove(SelectedItem);
            SelectedItem = null;
        }

        public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }

        private Person selectedItem;

        public Person SelectedItem
        {
            get { return selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                if (selectedItem == value)
                    return;

                selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```